# is <* equivalent to the following with respect to parsec?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I recently started learning to use Parsec to write parsers. I am wondering if the following is true:

Even though `<*` is implemented as `(<*) = liftA2 const`, when used with parsec, is it the same as:

```
p1 <* p2 = do { r1 <- p1; _ <- p2; return r1 }
```

And it seems that when using parsec the operator `*>` and `>>` are exactly the same since they both throw away the result of the first parser?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, when a type has instances of both `Applicative` and `Monad`, it is considered polite for those instances to agree in the way you suggest, at least semantically. In some instances the `Applicative` version may be more efficient (in some cases even asymptotically so!), though for parsec at least this is not the case; from the source:

```
instance Applicative.Applicative (ParsecT s u m) where
    pure = return
    (<*>) = ap -- TODO: Can this be optimized?
```

Comment: @dfeuer Okay, I've taken the useless modifier out and replaced it with something precise.

Comment: Less pathologically, look at the difference between the `<*>` definitions in `Data.Sequence` in [containers-0.5.6.0](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.0/docs/src/Data-Sequence.html) vs. [containers-0.5.6.3](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/src/Data-Sequence.html). That was a lot of fun.